# Run python script with argument

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to run a script with an argument from shell:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe E:\python.py argument1
```

I would like use this argument as:

```
def main(argv):
    cmdargs = str(sys.argv[1])

    file = open('E:\file_'+ cmdargs + '.txt',"r")
```

In result I would like get:

```
E:\file_argument1.txt
```

Comment: You basically already have the solution. Import the `sys` module and access `sys.argv[1]` (which is already a string), exactly as you've shown. What problem do you have?

Comment: massacre, I was looking for the result not in this location

Answer (score 0):

As @Kemp said, just import `sys` and use `sys.argv[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the suggested solution for parsing the arguments or try using the [argparse](https://docs.python.org/2.7/howto/argparse.html#argparse-tutorial) library which would the recommended way to do this.